# Redirect::to does not redirect with 302

Tags: laravel-4, http-status-code-302

I have this code somewhere in my controller :

```
return Redirect::to('event/create')->withErrors($validation);
```

Why do I get the statusCode 200 and not 302 ?

Thanks

ps: I use `Response::json()` to verify

Answer (score 2):

It *is* returning a 302 for the page that the validation errors occurs on.

But then the page you are redirected to will give you a status of 200 (because it loads correctly) - so when you run `Response::json()` on *that* page you get 200.

You can test in your browser developer toolkit that a 302 and a 200 is thrown:

[image: Status code check]

Comment: Yes you're right! So in my method, I would like to know if the request is a 200 or 302. How can I do that? http_response_code() seems to return 200 in both cases :/

Comment: Why do you want to know if its a 302 on your other method? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm generating an uniqid for a input[type=hidden] in a form. When errors on validation, I don't want to regenerate this uniqid. So I thought about this solution ... It's strange that it's not possible:o

Comment: So just do isset($errors) - no need to worry about the 302 - you already know if there are errors or not! :)

Comment: Yes you're right! There are others solutions, but I really wanted to detect the redirect ;)

Comment: But you *are* detecting the redirect. If isset($errors) == true, that is exactly the same thing as "detect redirect". If you want - you could set a variable ->withRedirect(true) and in your other method do isset($redirect)

Comment: Yes of course :) But I wanted to know how to detect a redirect with the http statusCode ;)